# Clock source of an STM32G030K6T6

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, clock, crystal

I am currently designing a GPS tracker and have decided to go with an STM, choosing just STM32G030K6T6 ([datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32g030j6.pdf)).

I currently have the following pinout configured:

[image: my pinout]

My question is, since there is no OSC_OUT pin, am I not allowed to use an oscillator crystal? Or should I use OSC_EN as such?

Alternatively should I use a dedicated IC?

Comment: Such an unfortunate chip... it has LSE, but cannot use it for PLL and doesn't have MSI to  automatically trim it by LSE, as some other chips do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the package types without the OSC_OUT pin, you cannot use a high-speed crystal oscillator. You will have to use some other oscillator type (like active oscillator or internal), or some other package.

You cannot use the OSC_EN pin as OSC_OUT.